# Installing Ubuntu on blank hard drive

Tags: system-installation

Ok so I took the hard drive out of my old laptop to use as an external however now I want to use it in the old laptop again so that I can mess with Linux. Again, I did reformat it to the "default settings" which was FAT. I have installed Ubuntu on a flash drive the way that the website has says however when i put it in and restart my computer it says "Please remove all disks and restart computer". How can i solve this problem and install Ubuntu properly?

Comp Specs:
Sony Vaio
I3 processor 
4 gb of ram
500gb HD

Comment: Have you trie the USB drive on another computer? Are you sure it works?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure your BIOS to boot from USB and not from the HD. How it is done change from computer to computer so you may refer to the docs of your system if you don't know how to do this. Usually modern BIOS have an option to press a key while booting and offer to change the boot order which is easier than changing the default in BIOS.

If you already are booting from the USB pendrive, the pendrive is not bootable so you should verify that you completed all the steps while installing ubuntu on it, including writing GRUB on it and not on your HD.